# java.lang.NullPointerException occured while implementing driver initialization through inheritance

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, test-automation-framework, exception

**Base class:**

```
public class Base {

  public WebDriver driver ;

   @BeforeMethod
  public void initialize() {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/apple/eclipse-workspace/Selenium/src/Google/chromedriver");

    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver() ;
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("https://google.com");
  }

   @AfterMethod
   public void exitdriver() {
      driver.close();
   }
}
```

**Page Class:**

```
public class Pages {

  WebDriver driver ;

   public Pages( WebDriver driver)
   {
        this.driver = driver ;
   }

    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = ".//*[@id='lst-ib']")
    WebElement search ;

    public void Googletext() throws InterruptedException
    {
        search.sendKeys("Test");
    }
}
```

**Main Class**

```
 public class Front extends Base {


  @Test
  public void Login() throws InterruptedException {

      Pages PagesObj = new Pages(driver);
      PagesObj.Googletext();  
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect? Your code does not make sense. Try to use debugging before asking for assistance.

Comment: Sorry , some mistake in copying code here , please check now. I want to initialize & quit driver in my base class which i want to use as inheritance in my main class( through extend ). there is one more class which has all the functions, which i want to call at my main function

Comment: what `driver` are you sending as a parameter for the Pages Constructor?

Comment: WebDriver driver

Comment: you need to give more of the code, you don't have everything posted here.

Comment: StackOverFlow is the good resource of knowledge and professional advise. But prior going here and posting questions, make sure you've tried everything and made a research on the other forums. If you don't understand the principles of OOP, it's better to read a book / take a course, because explaining this topic over here is just impossible.

Comment: @Alexey R.  - can you please help me out here as well . TIA ( Getting null point error at same , ( search.sendkeys)

Answer (score 0):

You were getting `NullpointerException` because you are declaring another `ChromeDriver` instance inside the `initialize()` method and creating an instance of `ChromeDriver` object whose scope is limited to `initialize()` method itself.

Make the following corrections in the code:

**In Base class:**

```
public void initialize() {
 ..some code

  driver = new ChromeDriver() ;

..some code 
}
```

And you don't need another `WebDriver driver` declaration in `Front` class.( you can remove it).

**In Front class:**

```
public class Front extends Base {

  @Test
  public void Login() throws InterruptedException {
      Pages PagesObj = new Pages(driver);
      PagesObj.Googletext();  
  }
}
```

So, now the driver gets initialized in `initialize()` method of `Base` class and the same driver instance is passed through to your Page object.